# DotNetNuke jquery script in container

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke

Hello
I've made a container in DNN but i don't know how to implement jquery script to the container.
Does anybody know how this is done?

Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do it properly, you'll need to write some code (which you can do inside of your container).  First, you'll want to request jQuery from the framework.  Then, add your plugin script (the best way is probably to use [`Page.ClientScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fedca103.aspx), so that the script doesn't get added multiple times when the container is used multiple times on the page.

```
<script runat="server">
    Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestRegistration()
        Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("myscript", ResolveClientUrl("scripts/jquery.myplugin.js"))
    End Sub
</script>
```

I would probably alter the plugin script and include a call at the end to call the plugin on whatever elements you're enhancing:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.my-container .header').pluginize();
});
```

Comment: Where to put it (ascx or htm?)
Want to say i've been working with dnn for about 2 weeks.
so i don't know where to put the different things.
Thank you for you answer hope you can help me.

Comment: Running code in your skin will only work in ascx skins, not html skins.