# jquery SlideToggle in dnn

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotnetnuke, slidetoggle

I'm trying to make a infobox when i click the head the content slides down
but when i do it it just slides down and then up again.
It is in a ascx document and i need to use it on a dotnetnuke container
it works perfectly in a html file
here's the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.head').click(function () {
            $('.content').slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.textbox .content:eq(1)').hide();
    $('.textbox .head').click(function () {
        if ($(this).next('.content').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).next('.content').slideUp();
        } else {
            $(this).next('.content').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you'll toggle all of the content areas if you have multiples of the same container on the page.

The second example looks like it should work, but, again, if you have multiple instances of the container, and that script is in the container itself, you'll register the handler multiple times.  Try moving the script to an external file and referencing it in code, so it only gets included once.  See [DotNetNuke jquery script in container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5339988/2688) for an example of that.